# Dendrobium nobile: How and when to cut and pot new plant (keiki) from mother?

Tags: plant-care, propagation

I have a (slightly neglected) dendrobium nobile that has started to grow new plants at the top of two old stalks. One is staring to show roots (see picture below), the other is still a bit smaller.

[image: Dendrobium baby]

While I have seen this phenomenon with phalenopsis orchids, it's new to me with a dendrobium nobile.

So what's next? Should I

- cut off the baby plant (keiki?) and put it in its own pot? (now? once it has more roots?)
- bend the mother stalk down, let the new plant take root in a second container and cut then?
- do something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the keiki grow on until it has more leaves and more than two roots - preferably around 4 to 6 roots. Once its achieved that sort of size, cut it off the mother stem just below the point from which it's growing, without damaging its roots, and pot up in the usual way.